# I use scanf to get input, and I use printf to check the input.... and then the input is incorrect when I go to use it

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char, printf

If I save a certain character to memory using the `scanf("%c",&variableName)` method, it saves properly and I can double check the character has been saved using printf("%c",variableName). My issue is that I can't figure out how to properly access this piece of data when doing an if-statement.

Without further adieu, here is my little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *character;

    printf("Please enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",&character);
    printf("\nYou entered %c",character);

    if (character == 'a')
        printf("Yay!");
    else
        printf("Noo!");
}
```

If I enter the character 'a' when prompted, my program will print out *"You entered a"*
Which leads me to believe I did it right...

The problem is that this does not work with my if-statement... even though when I printf "character," I get 'a', it does not register as 'a' in my if statement.

I tried changing it to `if(&character == 'a')` and  `if(*character == 'a')` , but neither of those worked.

**What is the issue here? 'a' is clearly stored somewhere in memory, but when I try to use it for my if statement it doesn't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `character` variable as a pointer to char, not a char. Just change your declaration to:

```
char character;
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. 

Ugh, it seems so obvious after you pointing it out to me :P

Comment: I'll accept answer, but it won't let me upvote because I don't have 15 reputation :(